# Could you explain Test Driven Development using my specific example?

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, tdd

I am trying to understand Test Driven Development, but still do not get it.

Let's imagine, that we need to write a function, that returns power of a number.

```
def power_of_a_number ( number, power ):
.... <some code here>...
```

According to TDD, we need to write a test first. How do we write the test?

Well, I know, that 2^2 = 4.

So I expect the function to return "4" if we pass "2" and "2" as parameters to it.

OK, I write the test:

```
if power_of_a_number ( 2, 2 ) == 4:
    print ( "The test is passed" )
```

After that test the function looks simple:

```
def power_of_a_number ( number, power ):
    return 4
```

Whooo, the test is passed! The function is written!

But I did not achieve the results - the function I have written is still crap.

So, I can extend the test. What else do I know? Well, 3^4 = 81. OK, let's extend the test!

```
if power_of_a_number ( 2, 2 ) == 4 and power_of_a_number ( 3, 4 ) == 81:
    print ( "The test is passed" )
```

Brilliant. Now the function looks much more advanced:

```
def power_of_a_number ( number, power ):
    if number == 2 and power == 2:
        return 4
    if number == 3 and power == 4:
        return 81
```

Once again the tests are passed! And once again the function is incomplete.

Well, we can add 5^2 = 25.

```
if power_of_a_number ( 2, 2 ) == 4 and power_of_a_number ( 3, 4 ) == 81 and power_of_a_number ( 5, 2 ) == 25:
    print ( "The test is passed" )
```

...

```
def power_of_a_number ( number, power ):
    if number == 2 and power == 2:
        return 4
    if number == 3 and power == 4:
        return 81
    if number == 5 and power == 2:
        return 25
```

And this way we can continue on and on...

What am I missing in this structure? What can formally be done according to TDD (!) to write the right test and to write the right code?

Thank you!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions on process aren't a very good fit for Stack Overflow.  You may find it more appropriate for [Programmers' Stack Exchange](//programmers.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @TobySpeight when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Answer (score 3):

TDD is 3 steps:

1. Write a failing test
2. Write the simplest code that passes
3. Refactor

In your first example, you skipped the first step. Something like this:

```
def power_of_a_number ( number, power ):
    return 0
```

The test fails. You then change it to `return 4` to get it to pass, which is correct.

Why is this important? By changing something in production code, you're getting test code to pass. You're flipping a switch on one end, and seeing the light change on the other end. This demonstrates that your test is working.

After that, you start adding more and more if-statements. That may be okay for step 2. But then you need to refactor. **One of the principles of TDD is that as test code becomes more specific, the production code becomes more general.**

TDD also follows [3 laws](https://qualitycoding.org/3-laws-tdd/):

1. You are not allowed to write any production code unless it is to make a failing unit test pass.
2. You are not allowed to write any more of a unit test than is sufficient to fail; and compilation failures are failures.
3. You are not allowed to write any more production code than is sufficient to pass the one failing unit test.

If these rules aren't driving you to implement power_of_a_number, then you need to rethink your tests. For an example of TDDing adding fractions (and its many tests), see J.B. Rainsberger's training [Add Fractions in Java Part 2](http://online-training.jbrains.ca/courses/wbitdd-01/lectures/133486)